# Handle onclick event of Html Button inside ListView

Tags: c#, html, listview, button, visual-studio-2017

I have been struggling to make this work, I have a ListView which has 2 buttons that basically are "Accept" and "Reject" to an image, these buttons are generated by the Listview itself so I can't assign an id. I can't use commandargument because they are html buttons, neither I can use linkbutton because they send a postback causing the page to refresh, can't use Asp buttons because the have an FA icon inside(I know I can download a library but I'm not sure about that), so the question is how I can make so when the use click one button, the other one shade into gray and when I click on a final button I loop through the listview and retrieve all the "Accepted" images?

List view Code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="listadoImg" runat="server" Visible="true" OnItemDataBound="listadoImg_DataBound"   >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imagen") %>' CssClass="card-img-top" />

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-7  text-right ">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" Text='<%# string.Concat("SKU: ",Eval("sku"))%>' runat="server"
                                CssClass="" Font-Size="Small"  /><br />

                            <asp:Label ID="Label17" Font-Size="Small" Text='<%# Eval("marca").ToString() + " " + Eval("descripcion").ToString()%>' runat="server" CssClass="labelImagenes" /><br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label15" Font-Size="Small" Text='<%# string.Concat("Precio Normal: ",Eval("precioNormal"))%>'
                                runat="server"  CssClass="labelImagenes" /><br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPrecioOferta" Font-Size="Small" Text='<%# string.Concat("Precio Oferta: ",Eval("precioPublicacion"))%>'
                                runat="server" CssClass="labelImagenes" />
                        </div>
                        <%--<div class="col-5 text-left mt-3">
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x ico-verde"></i>&nbsp; <span>Aprobar </span></p>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-ban fa-2x mt-1 ico-rojo"></i>&nbsp; <span>Rechazar </span></p>
                        </div>--%>
                        
                        <div class="col-5 text-left mt-3">
                            
                            
                            <button  type="button" id="btnAceptado1"   class="btn btn-light" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; left: 5%; font-size: 18px; top: 3%; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; margin-top: -10px; border: 1px solid transparent"
                                aria-label="Left Align" onclick="CambiarAceptado1()"   >
                               <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x ico-verde"></i>
                                 <span>Aprobar </span>
                            </button>
                             
                            <button  type="button" id="btnAceptado2"  class="btn btn-light" style="position: relative; display: none; left: 5%; font-size: 18px; top: 3%; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; margin-top: -10px; border: 1px solid transparent"
                                aria-label="Left Align" onclick="CambiarAceptado2()" >
                                <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x ico-plomo"></i>
                                 <span>Aprobar </span>
                            </button>

                          
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <br />
                            <button type="button" id="btnRechazado1" class="btn btn-light" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; left: 5%; top: 3%; padding: 0px; font-size: 18px; background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid transparent"
                                aria-label="Left Align" onclick="CambiarRechazado1()">
                                <i class="fa fa-ban fa-2x mt-1 ico-rojo"></i>
                                Rechazar
                            </button>
                             <button   id="btnRechazado2" type="button"   class="btn btn-light" style="position: relative; display: none; left: 5%; top: 3%; padding: 0px; font-size: 18px; background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid transparent"
                                aria-label="Left Align" onclick="CambiarRechazado2()" >
                                <i class="fa fa-ban fa-2x mt-1 ico-plomo"></i>
                                Rechazar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

So far I've been able to make something similar to one row which make it disappear when is blank like this:

```
 protected void listadoImg_DataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPrecioOfe;
        
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            lblPrecioOfe = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPrecioOferta");
            System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            string precioPub = rowView["precioPublicacion"].ToString();
            if (precioPub == "")
            {
                lblPrecioOfe.Text = "";
            }
        }  
    }
```

The images look like this:

[image]

currently I can make it work with the JavaScript which is used in the buttons at the moment but only for the first object in the List.

The JS used is this:

```
 function CambiarAceptado1() {            
            document.getElementById('btnAceptado1').style.display = 'inline-block';                
            document.getElementById('btnAceptado2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('btnRechazado1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('btnRechazado2').style.display = 'inline-block';
        
    }
    function CambiarAceptado2() {

        document.getElementById('btnAceptado1').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('btnAceptado2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('btnRechazado1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('btnRechazado2').style.display = 'inline-block';

    }
    function CambiarRechazado1() {

        document.getElementById('btnAceptado1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('btnAceptado2').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('btnRechazado1').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('btnRechazado2').style.display = 'none';

    }
    function CambiarRechazado2() {

        document.getElementById('btnAceptado1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('btnAceptado2').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('btnRechazado1').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('btnRechazado2').style.display = 'none';

    }
```

Comment: If you want an icon inside of an asp.net button, you should be able to use <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lbHello"><i class="fa fa-blah"></i> Hello</asp:LinkButton> and then use that to call your postback.  You can also look into update panels if you want to prevent the page flicker on postback.

Comment: Jquery Ajax with page web methods is another option

Comment: Already solved it , thanks in advanced, i'll be posting the solution as soon as i finish the code, ty @Drewskis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the answer in case someone else get the same problem:

First in the databound i define 4 html buttons 2 for accepted (on and off) an 2 for rejected(same):

```
 protected void listadoImg_DataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblPrecioOfe;

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            lblPrecioOfe = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPrecioOferta");
            System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            string precioPub = rowView["precioPublicacion"].ToString();
            if (precioPub == "")
            {
                lblPrecioOfe.Text = "";
            }
        }

        HtmlButton bot = (HtmlButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnAceptado1");
        HtmlButton bot2 = (HtmlButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnAceptado2");
        HtmlButton bot3 = (HtmlButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnRechazado1");
        HtmlButton bot4 = (HtmlButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnRechazado2");

        bot.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CambiarAceptado1(" + bot.ClientID.Substring(bot.ClientID.ToString().Length -1)+")");
        bot2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CambiarAceptado2(" + bot.ClientID.Substring(bot.ClientID.ToString().Length - 1) + ")");
        bot3.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CambiarRechazado1(" + bot.ClientID.Substring(bot.ClientID.ToString().Length - 1) + ")");
        bot4.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CambiarRechazado2(" + bot.ClientID.Substring(bot.ClientID.ToString().Length - 1) + ")");


    }
```

each of them send the last char of the clientid of the control so in the javascript i recieve them to find the specific control in the page like this :

```
function CambiarAceptado1(valor) {

        document.getElementById('listadoImg_btnAceptado1_' + valor ).style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('listadoImg_btnAceptado2_' + valor).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('listadoImg_btnRechazado1_' + valor).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('listadoImg_btnRechazado2_' + valor).style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById("listadoImg_hdfAprobacion_" + valor).value = "1";

    }
```

also i define a hiddenfield to store the value if is accepted or rejected , hope this will be usefull.